# making 1's complement, why it doesn't work if i put a negative number

Tags: c, arrays

it works well if i put positive numbers but it doesn't work if i put negative numbers.
however it works if i copy and paste the only 1's complement part's codes.
if i put -12, it shows absolute : 10001100 and 1's complement: 11110011. 
idk why it doesn't work help :(

```
    //1's complement_1
    {
        printf("\n 1's complement:");
        if (decimal_1 < 0)
        { decimal_1 = - decimal_1; bi_1[0] = 1; }
            for(i_1=7; i_1>0 ;i_1--)
            {
                bi_1[i_1]=decimal_1%2;
                decimal_1=decimal_1/2;
            }
            Fcomplement_1[0]=1;
            for(i_1=1 ; i_1<8; i_1++ )
            {
                if (bi_1[i_1]==0)
                    Fcomplement_1[i_1]=1;
                else
                    Fcomplement_1[i_1]=0;
            }
            for(i_1=0; i_1<8; i_1++)
                printf("%d", Fcomplement_1[i_1]);
        }
        else
            for (i_1=0 ; i_1<8 ; i_1++)
                printf("%d",bi_1[i_1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (decimal_1 < 0)
{
  decimal_1 = - decimal_1;
  bi_1[0] = 1;
}` - this is what you do. What do you think this code does?! What's the problem? What would the result be if the result looked as if the program "worked"?

Comment: Why are you assuming the length of equivalent binary conversion to be 7?

Comment: I assume this is an academic exercise?  If not the ones complement can be effected by the `~` operator and integer to binary string conversion by `itoa()`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala oh i think yours also good but i change it in other way. i think 'decimal_1<0' was not the problem

Comment: @abhilash_goyal cuz the exercise assume the bit as 8

Comment: @Clifford yes it is academic excercise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first output is not the absolute value, it is the sign+magnitude representation: `-12` gives `10001100`.

The second loop is too complicated, you should just invert the bits in positions 1 to 7 if the bit at position zero (the sign) is `1`.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int decimal_1, bi_1[99], i_1;
    int decimal_2, bi_2[99], i_2;
    int Fcomplement_1[99]; 

    printf("Input two decimal numbers: ");
    if (scanf("%d%d", &decimal_1, &decimal_2) != 2)
        return 1;

    // decimal_1 
    {
        if (decimal_1 < 0) {
            decimal_1 = -decimal_1;
            bi_1[0] = 1;
        } else { 
            bi_1[0] = 0;

        for (i_1 = 7; i_1 > 0; i_1--) {
            bi_1[i_1] = decimal_1 % 2;
            decimal_1 = decimal_1 / 2;
        }

        printf("absolute value: 0");
        for (i_1 = 1; i_1 < 8; i_1++)
            printf("%d", bi_1[i_1]);
        printf("\n");
        printf("sign+magnitude representation: ");
        for (i_1 = 0; i_1 < 8; i_1++)
            printf("%d", bi_1[i_1]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    //1's complement_1
    {
        Fcomplement_1[0] = bi_1[0];
        for (i_1 = 1; i_1 < 8; i_1++) {
            Fcomplement_1[i] = bi_1[i] ^ bi_1[0];
        }
        printf("1's complement: ");
        for (i_1 = 0; i_1 < 8; i_1++)
            printf("%d", Fcomplement_1[i_1]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: wow your codes are so clear!

Comment: @user9751004: Thank you, the code would be even more readable with simpler variable names, such as `i`, `n1`, `buf1`... but that's a matter of choice and local conventions.

Comment: thanks Chqrlie! i changed your codes little(as you know signbit should not be changed) and how could i distinguish positive number and negative number? your codes are perfectly right in case of negative number but in case of positive number, 1's complement should be same as sign+magnitude representation.if you have little more time could you check my codes one more?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210803/how-do-i-use-if-to-distinguish-negative-number-and-positive-number-in-my-codes

Comment: @user9751004: you have a good point, the complement loop should start at `1`. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In the 1's complement block you test `decimal_1 < 0`, which is never true, because it was modified to zero in the previous block.

You should perhaps copy the user input to a second variable so you can process the unmodified value.